# Extract image path from HTML in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Help!!!
I am fairly new to iPhone App development and I am caught up with parsing!
I am trying to read the feeds from a URL which ends in .cms
I was able to get the text from the source and remove the HTML using the flattenHTML code but I am having trouble with extracting the path for the image.
The path for the image is in something like:  ....(text+html)...><img src="http://www....
If anybody could please help and suggest how i can get the path for the image extracted... :((

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may apply a regular expression on your text to extract the path.

The pattern would be something like `<img.*src?=?"(.*?)"`

Comment: No. Don't. No ReGex for HTML. Use an XML parser. HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be correctly parsed with RegEx, it is a subset of XML.

Comment: What about single quotes? What about no quotes? What about whitespace? Newlines?

Comment: I totally agree with you, except if he's having a "one shot problem", or working with only one feed, always generated the same way. If it's not the case, ReGex are not an option.

Comment: Well if I am not wrong, XML parser works fine as long as it is a .xml file. This URL that I'm working with has a .cms extension that seems to be a little different than regular xml. When i extract the contents inside the <description> tag pair, I get the description as well as some HTML with the image URL included in it. I am unable to extract it.